# Critical point of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

An exercise I'm doing is asking me to show $\partial_z f=\partial_{\bar{z}}f=0$ is equivalent to $\partial_x f=\partial_{y}f=0$ using these two definitions:
$$\partial_{z}z^{n}=nz^{n-1}$$ and
$$\partial_{\bar{z}}\bar{z}^{n}=n\bar{z}^{n-1}$$
I for the life of me cannot figure out how to start this problem, I tried using the Wirtinger derivatives but the way I was doing it was leading me nowhere. Please someone help!

Comment: surely just by the definition of Wirtinger derivatives it should be enough? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives (see def 1). And werent those definitions specific to $z^n$ as opposed to any function $f$?

Comment: Yes they should be, but I am really stuck on how to go about showing it. I tried to do the expression with the partials with respect to x and y, then setting those to zero but I didn't know what to do next

Comment: set them to be zero and treat the equations as simultaneous equations